# Decryption with openssl of a string encrypted with nodejs crypto (public private key pair)

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I'm quite new in the encryption world and I'm facing a problem not sure if I can resolve or if my previous steps were wrong.

**Situation :**

The user generate a public/private key pair with this command :

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
```

I will then encrypt a generated UUID in a nodejs application with the public key with this code :

```
import * as crypto from "crypto";

// ...

const uuidBuffer = Buffer.from(generatedUUID);
const encryptedUUID = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, keyBuffer).toString("base64");
```

Then this encrypted UUID is stored in a DB.

Later the user can download in my frontend the encrypted UUID coming from the DB in a .txt file.

```
const blob = new Blob([encryptedUUID], { type: "txt" });
saveAs(blob, "encrypted-password.txt");
```

And then it should be able to decrypt the generated UUID from the .txt file with this command **(which is not working)** :

```
openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -inkey private_key.pem -in encrypted-password.txt -out decrypted-password.txt
```

I have this error :

```
Public Key operation error
40A79CA2EC7F0000:error:0200006C:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:data greater than mod len:../crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:406:
```

I understand based on my research it's related to the size of what's encrypted, but I'm really confused because if I decrypt using nodejs with this code it's working :

```
import * as crypto from "crypto";

// ...
const dec1 = crypto.privateDecrypt(
  privateKey,
  Buffer.from(encryptedUUID, "base64")
);
console.log(decryptedUUID.toString());
```

Am I doing something wrong during the key generation, encryption or the openssl decryption?

In advance any help is much appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: I believe you are using node.js to encrypt the UUID and to decrypt you are using OpenSSL. Not too sure this arrangement should work as they might be using different algorithms for this operation.

Comment: based on my understanding node crypto publicEncrypt and the openssl command I use are both using RSA algorithm.

Comment: RSA encryption is limited in the length of data it can encrypt. You are using a key of 2048 bit length = 256 byte. As there are some bytes used for padding you get a maximum of (about) 200 bytes. So - how long is your plaintext (UUID) ?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFehr I encrypt a UUID like this : 3a47d39a-ff59-11ec-b939-0242ac120002

Comment: And when encrypted by node I will store a base64 string like this

OzQ5eM3pqEzLuXrAGoAwuhHnayT6B/f5jxV3+GT9nzgioEgDcpYUg18i/CgajM8B6cImDtlBzK4ZoK5rhuAW58HAGW5RCU9QRdr8WwZdlViqoetfbxlwf+kiU3/lUBlZOwXyjN6BtQyu1MeUVGYz5Oo6V0a9vcjevukQMjEcA2WjIHzcA5N7G+vZj3MAZh0S8S2P++cncquD3gQdr6gDusR796HC9ETuGkgyJwZVbsTJumoi84V1QxpaHFzEhHN18JV7SGvyS6FhIEqLWwxZTOuduPbr293jQAs6JZp4SupJMcZOkbhDuPthGQF2ZG4sQU3EkmZXmLCeODaEpGNpbg==

is this value too big maybe to be decrypted ?

Comment: **It's base64.** Your nodejs encryption encodes to base64 and your nodejs decryption decodes from base64, but your openssl commandline doesn't. Since base64 is longer than raw data, openssl detects this as 'data too long'. Do `openssl base64 -d -A <encryptedb64 >encryptedbin` then do your `pkeyutl -decrypt` on `encryptedbin`. Or reconsider whether you need the base64 in the nodejs versions and db -- most DBMSes since about 1990 can handle binary.

Comment: thank you in just figured out the same! the next I was not able to decrypt with this error : RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error

and actually just found node publicEncrypt use OAEP so I have to specify -oaep to my command too.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it with some more research and help in the comments thanks Dave.

The missing step was to convert back the encrypted password text file from base64.

```
openssl base64 -d -A <encrypted-password.txt >encrypted.bin
```

Then I can use the openssl command to decrypt the encrypted.bin file.

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private_key.pem -in encrypted.bin -out decrypted-password.txt -oaep
```

Important note, I needed to add the `-oaep` argument also **because node crypto use OAEP**. without this argument there was still an error because of the padding that time!